# How to update nomad job from one namespace to another?

Tags: nomad, hashicorp

I would like to change namespace of a job in Nomad cluster from one namespaceA to namespaceB.

When I change a namespace in a job UI of Nomad, I notice that it creates 2 jobs in namespaceA and namespaceB.

How can I just keep one namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Updating namespace in the job of the UI will create another job in another namespace --> resulting to 2 jobs (It is the normal behavior of nomad)

To update the job namespace to another job and keep only one namespace :

1. Create the new namespace if it does not exist : `nomad namespace apply -description "MyNewNamespace description" <my-new-namespace>`
2. Stop the job (this step is necessary otherwise Nomad duplicates the job when changing namespace) : `nomad job stop <myJob>`
3. Change the namespace attribute in the job.nomad file

```
job "myJob" {

    ## Change namespace here
    namespace = "MyNewNamespace"

}
```

4. Launch the job `nomad job run <path/to>/myjob.nomad`
5. Verify : `nomad job status`
6. Permanently delete the old job from the old namespace `nomad job stop -namespace=<oldNamespace> --purge <myJob>`